# Reading doubles with scanf- decimals causing newline issues

Tags: c, double, scanf, newline

I'm trying to fill 3 'slot' structs(I'm aware I allocated more memory) which consist of an int a a double[2]. However, when I input a number with a decimal point several lines are consumed- here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "sshm.h"

struct Slot
{ int x;

  double y[2];

} ;

int main(){
    int shm_key = 123456, shmid, i;
    struct Slot slot;
    struct Slot* shared;
    
    shmid = shm_get(shm_key, (void**)&shared, 5 * sizeof(struct Slot));
    if (shmid<0) {printf("error with get"); return 0;}

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        printf("Enter an integer: ");
        scanf(" %i", &shared[i].x);
        printf("Enter a double: ");
        scanf(" %f", &shared[i].y[0]);
        printf("Enter a second double: ");
        scanf(" %f", &shared[i].y[1]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

edit:
example of several lines being consumed-

```
Enter an integer: 5
Enter a double: 6.6
Enter a second double:Enter an integer:Enter a double:
```

Comment: "several lines are consumed". What does that mean exactly? For clarity show the exact input, actual result and expected result.

Comment: 1) Please post the complete code, including `shm_get`. 2) Use `"%lf"` to read a double.

Comment: @kaylum good point, no idea why I didn't. updated to add!

Comment: @dxiv confused as to what you mean- this is the whole program and shm_get is there? this is creating the shared memory if that helps

Comment: @man_idk I am not familiar with `shm_get` (there is a Posix `shmget` but that's obviously not the one called here). Can you duplicate the issue using just `Slot shared[3];`?